# how to display up to 1 decimal place

Tags: apache-poi, jxl, jexcelapi

I am using jxl-2.6.3.jar.

I want to display bigdecimals, which are up to 1 decimal point.

If i write like below, then 1.2 is displayed as "1.2" , but 1.0 appears as "1." .
I need 0 as well in case of 1.0, i.e "1.0" instead of simply "1." .

```
BigDecimal number = new BigDecimal(1.0);
NumberFormat dp1 = new NumberFormat("#.#");
WritableCellFormat format = new WritableCellFormat(dp1);
workSheet.addCell(new Number(1, 1, number.doubleValue(),format));
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the number format `"#.0"`.  A "#" character indicates that a digit should be there only if necessary to represent the number, and a "0" character indicates that a digit must be there, even if it's unnecessary to represent the number.  For further reference, please see the [Excel format symbols](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/number-format-codes-HP005198679.aspx).

The `"#.0"` format will work whether you are using `NumberFormat` in JXL or you are creating a data format string with `DataFormat` in Apache POI.